# Powershell sort float data in csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I use this command:

```
import-csv my.csv | select Date, Balance | sort Balance | select -first 10
```

The Balance column is float data, but it is sorted as string. How to sort it as number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
import-csv my.csv | select Date, Balance | sort {[double]$_.Balance} | select -first 10
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But in the msdn's sort-object examples, they do not use this conversion. When this kind of conversion is required on numeric fields?

Comment: @Ryan In this case (import from csv) the values of balance column are probably treated as [string] type then you need to cast then to [double] or [float] or [decimal]. Glad to help!